# Receiving error "use of local unassigned Variable"

Tags: c#, asp.net

The issue here is that when i call variable "game" it returns and unassigned variable compilation error. As i understand it, when I assign the new value to a variable, it is meant to initialize that variable.

```
 public class GameController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Game
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int pins = rnd.Next(1, 10);

            Games game = new Games()
                {
                frames = game.frames,
                Pins = game.Pins,
                Score = game.Score,
                player = game.player,
                };

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace webBowlingProject.Models
{
public class Games
    {
    public int frames { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Pins { get; set; }
    public string player { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are coming from a model, the intent was to instantiate them, and then use them in a view to capture and store information about "game"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be instead

```
Games game = new Games()
{
    frames = frames,
    Pins = pins,
    Score = Score,
    player = player,
};
```

That means the first Left hand side variable is the name of the properties of the class and Right hand side variable name is the value you wanted to assign. Now when you say `game.frames` or `game.Pins` the problem is that your game which is just initializing (In Process) has no value in the properties of its object

You can also use Visual Studio intellisense in this context. as soon as you put your cursor in between `{` and `}` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> the list will populate the properties of the class called game. Just select one of them and press tab and then press `=` and then fill in the value you wanted to assign to that property of your class.

Comment: Happy to help @JoshuaPearson :) Happy Coding